# Powershell - Try Catch - Non Powershell Errors

Tags: powershell, try-catch, iperf, iperf3

Is it possible to create a try-catch that catches a non-Powershell cmdlet error?

Example Error:

```
iperf3: error - unable to connect to server: Connection timed out
```

I want to catch that error and then try a different server for redundancy.

Thank you for the assist.

Comment: No, it is not possible to do this with a standard shell command. May be possible with .NET processes, otherwise it's limited to cmdlets and .NET code invoked from within Powershell

Answer (score 0):

you can try to build your own powershell function and throw an error with "throw " but you have to identify the error on your own within the powershell function